# How to Clear values from ListBox without removing List items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my situation When I use productsLocLB.items.Clear(). it removes All items instead of removing only values.

```
ListBox x:Name="productsLocLB"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" BorderThickness="0" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListboxItemPanel}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,25,0,0" Height="564" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RackListBoxItemStyle}"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!--User Info Cadview item Tamplate -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_OnMouseDownOrTouchDown" TouchDown="Grid_OnMouseDownOrTouchDown">
                    <Image x:Name="productLocImg" Width="150"  Source="{Binding SPImage}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Label Content="{Binding ProductName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Background="#99000000"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Avalability}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Background="#90FFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!---->
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListItem></ListItem>
<ListItem></ListItem>
<ListItem></ListItem>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: Is your `ItemsSource` set via a `Binding`?

Comment: Yes it is @MightyBadaboom

Comment: And you only want to set (for example) `ProductName = string.Empty` in every entry?

Comment: You are working a bit wrongly with UI in WPF. Normally you have to bind `ListBox.ItemsSource` to collection and perform operations (insert, as in previous question, or delete) with that collection. Start with [tutorials](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/).

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for this. 
Actually, i'm not an expert in wpf.
I normally use listbox.items.Add() and listbox.items.Clear() in binding as well as normal Listbox .

Comment: You really should read some basics about MVVM and binding if you do so. You should not change the `listbox.Items`. You should change the items in the collection you've bound your `ItemsSource` too.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
productsLocLB.items.Clear()
```

and write instead (assuming your collection which is bound to the `ItemsSource`is called `MyItems` and you want to set `ProductName = string.Empty;` for each entry in this collection.

```
foreach(var item in MyItems)
{
    ProductName = string.Empty;
}
```

You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well or the UI won't be notized and the new values won't shown.